# Error deploying EJBs in Wildfly 8 (JBOSS 8)

Tags: jboss, ejb-3.0, wildfly-8

I am getting error when I am trying to deploy EJB in Wildfly 8. I am trying to place my ejb.ear file which contains (beans.jar file with all bean and remote classes and meta-inf folder with ejb-jar.xml and jboss.xml) in wildfly8/standalone/deployments folder.
It shows me all the module names and jndi names for all the bean files I have placed. But after showing following is the error I get.

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."ejbs.ear"."beans.jar".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."ejbs.ear"."beans.jar".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment "beans.jar" of deployment "ejbs.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [wildfly-server-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011058: Failed to install component ReportBean
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ComponentInstallProcessor.deploy(ComponentInstallProcessor.java:109)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.session.SessionBeanObjectViewConfigurator$2.configureDependency(SessionBeanObjectViewConfigurator.java:94)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.session.SessionBeanObjectViewConfigurator$2.configureDependency(SessionBeanObjectViewConfigurator.java:91)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ComponentInstallProcessor.deployComponent(ComponentInstallProcessor.java:151)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ComponentInstallProcessor.deploy(ComponentInstallProcessor.java:101)
    ... 6 more
```

Can someone please help.

Thanks,
Jack.